# React returning Component displays [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that has an event that gets called when a user clicks an item in a different component.  The function that gets called is intended to display a Div on the web page.  I can return an html string, to display the div, but I would rather but that HTML into its own component.  My function gets called, but if I try to return a components (instead of raw html) it shows the div but not text.  It just says [object Object].  The function that gets called looks like this:

```
function MyPage() {
   const nodeHoverTooltip = (node) => {
      return `<div>${node.name}</div>`;
      //displays fine
  };
  const nodeClickDetails = (node) => {
    if(node.nodeType === "somenode"){
        return (<MyNodeDetails></MyNodeDetails>);
        //this just displays [object, Object]
    }else if (node.nodeType === "anotherNodeType"){
        return `<div>Another Node Type Details</div>`;
        //displays fine
    }else{
        return `<div>More Details</div>`;
       //displays fine
    }    
  };

return (
    <div className="MyDiv">
      <header className="header">Some Examples</header>
      <section className="Main">
        <ForceGraph
          linksData={data.links}
          nodesData={data.nodes}
          nodeHoverTooltip={nodeHoverTooltip}
          nodeClickDetails = {nodeClickDetails}
        />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
export default MyPage;
```

**MyNodeDetails.jsx Component:**

```
  function MyNodeDetails ({data}) {
    return (
     <div>
         MyNodeDetails 
     </div>
    )
  }  
  export default MyNodeDetails
```

Is there a way to but the HTML into a component and not do raw HTML?

Comment: not exactly sure tbh, but aren't you passing / returning the invoked version of react component there ? which is an object right ?

Comment: <MyNodeDetails></MyNodeDetails> is a component, which I guess makes it an object I think.  It is essentially to be a Div popup, when the nodeClickDetails  fires

Comment: It looks like `ForceGraph`'s `nodeClickDetails` prop is expecting a function returning a string, not JSX. Without a [mcve], we can't really tell you more. Maybe React's [`renderToString` function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) could help, but it could also be a bad design or improper usage of the component in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that's handling displaying the the HTML code is setting the `innerHTML` of an element to the html *string* being returned. When you convert a component, which is an object, to a string it gets converted to `'[object Object]'`. You need to use JSX instead of strings.

Here's an example to show the difference between both approaches. I doubt your rendering function is using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but the idea of converting to string is what's important.

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM
const { useState } = React

const Test = () => <div>This is a test component</div>
const testHTML = '<div>This is a test html string</div>'

function App(){
  const [component, setComponent] = useState()
  const [html, setHTML] = useState();
  
  function useJSX(){
    setComponent(<Test />)
    setHTML(testHTML)
  }
  
  function useHTML(){
    setComponent(<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: <Test/>}}></div>)
    setHTML(<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: testHTML}}></div>)
  }
  
  
  return (<div>
  <button onClick={useJSX}>Use JSX</button>
  <button onClick={useHTML}>Use HTML</button>
    {component}
    {html}
  </div>)
}

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container); 
root.render(<App tab="home" />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```